# how can i choose the destination path for my python in the Centos 5.3

Tags: python, unix, centos

This may sound stupid but I'm trying to install python but it is installed in /usr/bin/ but I want to install it on /usr/local/bin. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could install Python from source, the [mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-March/012903.html) has instructions. There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622744/unable-to-install-python-without-sudo-access) question that someone asked before that is similar.